# Setting up a JTextField to receive input?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a JTextField​ to my GUI to adjust my
application so that it changes the label to whatever the user has typed when they hit return or enter. I am having trouble setting it up because right now no JTextField shows up. The rest of the code is misc stuff dealing with intro GUI material.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private int counter;

public void JButton() {
    JButton button = new JButton("Press Me!");
    counter = 0;
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyGUI.this, "Button was pressed " + 
                    counter + " times");
        }
    });
    add(button);
}

String input;

public void JText(){
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
add(textField);
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input = textField.getText();
    }
});
}

private String yes = "Yes"; 
private static final String ON = "On";
private static final String OFF = "Off";

private JButton onOff;

private MyGUI() {
    onOff = new JButton(OFF);
    onOff.addActionListener(this);
    add(onOff);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.print(yes);
    counter = counter + 1;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyGUI.this, "Button was pressed " + counter + " times");
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    switch(command){
    case ON:
        onOff.setText(OFF);
        break;

    case OFF:
        onOff.setText(ON);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(800, 800);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    MyGUI frame = new MyGUI();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you think that text field should be added do your frame?

Comment: @Pshemo I think immediately.

Comment: You are creating it and adding inside JText() method, but you never use that method.

Comment: @Pshemo okay, how would I use it?

Comment: You need to invoke it like any other methods. Since it doesn't need any arguments `JText()` will do. Where is up to you and your goals. One of possibilities is inside your `MyGUI` constructor. BTW you should probably use some layout managers to handle adding multiple elements in your container. For now consider adding `this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` in constructor (possibly at start).

Comment: @Pshemo Is there a way to have the JTextField not cover the entire screen? The on/off button is now invisible.

Comment: Re-read what @Pshemo said about layout managers.

Comment: Use layout manager: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: It all works. Cool thanks guys